# Swift UIBarButtonItem transform doesn't work in scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, transform

I have a custom nav item

```
lazy var closeBtn: UIBarButtonItem = {
    let closeBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
    closeBtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "icClose")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    closeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleClose), for: .touchUpInside)
    let leftBtn = UIBarButtonItem(customView: closeBtn)
    leftBtn.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -1, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    return leftBtn
}()
```

So on scroll, i want to change a scale of this item

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: value, y: value)
    }
```

It just doesn't do anything. Fun thing is that the same code works inside UIView.Animate

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: value, y: value)
     }
    }
```

But i want to transform it immediately based on offset value.

Comment: I think you should add `self.view.layoutIfNeeded` after applying the transform so that the view redraws itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help

Comment: Solved by adding translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false to customView

Comment: Perhaps you should answer your own question and mark it as the correct answer so that others may see it.